# Create div height 100%, but page scroll bar should not appear

Tags: css

I am create a div with 100% height
HTML

```
<div id="BottomShelf"></div>
```

CSS

```
#BottomShelf{ position:absolute; top:400px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%;; background:#d4b7a0; z-index:1;}
```

There is a page scroll showing up on the page, but I need a page scroll (not div scroll) only when there is content.  height:auto does not do the trick too.

I need the div to take the browser height irrespective to the height of the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set `top: 400px; bottom: 0;` instead of `top: 400px; height: 100%;`

**EDIT:** note that this might not work in IE6 (don't know about IE7)

Comment: It works with IE9, not sure on the version 8,7,6.  Anyways IE is not of priority for development :) Thanks.............

Answer (score 1):

The body tag has some default margin, so if you need a div to take the place as body, first set the body style to: `margin: 0;`

I tried creating a div with the following styles, and it seems to do what you want:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
```

`overflow: auto` will give the div a vertical scrollbar if the content exceeds the height.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryd the overflow:hidden; css style property?

Sorry it was overflow:hidden;

Comment: `overflow: none;` does not exist. i think what you want to write is `overflow: hidden;` - also, this won't meet the second requirement (show scrollbars if there is enough content)

Comment: Then you can always use overflow:hidden; and add overflow:scroll to the content css.